# EF Core DbSet null reference exception when using InMemory in unit tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my application I use EF Core using SQL Server. This all works fine. When I call a method that has, for example, the following code:

```
public void SomeMethod(int id)
{
    var user = _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Then this obviouslty returns a user when it finds one, or it returns `null` when it doesn't find a user with the given `id`.

But, in my unit tests I use the InMemory provider. When I call the same method from my unit test, it then throws an exception telling me that `_dbContext.Users` is `null`.

I know I can easily fix this by adding an empty list of users to the DbContext in my unit tests. But WHY is this different in my 'production' code?

A `DbSet` is *never* `null`. But it is when running from an InMemory proivder...

Is there a global setting I can use? So I don't have to setup every DbSet with an empty list to prevent these `null` exceptions that otherwise would never occur...

---

This is how I create my DbContext in my unit test:

I have a factory:

```
public static MyDbContext Create()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase($"{Guid.NewGuid()}")
        .Options;

    return new MyDbContext(options);
}
```

In my unit test I do:

```
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
    var context = InMemoryDbContextFactory.Create();

    // Example of how I add things to the DbContext (this works)
    context.Roles.Add(new UserRole { Id = 1, Name = "Test" });
    context.SaveChanges();

    var sut = new SutService(context);
    var result = sut.MyMethod();

    // Do assert...
}
```

PS.
I know my DbContext is not wrapped in a `using` statement. But even if it was, I would still have the same problem.

Comment: Can you show your code to create DbContext instance?

Comment: @H.Herzl Added a code example.

Comment: In examples for EF Core documentation, recommends to use two DbContext instances, the first one to seed data and the second one to perform operations for your components

Comment: Show your DbContext code please

Comment: Take a look on this: https://github.com/hherzl/EntityFrameworkCoreForEnterprise/blob/master/Code/Store/Store.API.UnitTests/SalesControllerTests.cs